# Unix diff command to find contents present in only 1 file

Tags: unix

The question is pretty naive but am reaching to forum as I don't seem to find any such option now. here is the background.. I used Unix diff command pretty extensively earlier (around 4+ years back) and used it to find contents which is there only in 1 of the file (not present at all in the second file).
I vaguely remember using something like `diff -12 or diff -23` or something like that. However I am not able to use the same command now and the

> "man page"

of diff command also does not show any such option. Has anyone used similar stuff earlier or used a different diff command for the same purpose. 
Any pointer will be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are looking for `comm` command

```
comm -23 file1 file2
```

Snippet from `man comm`

```
   -1     suppress lines unique to FILE1

   -2     suppress lines unique to FILE2

   -3     suppress lines that appear in both files
```

Comment: thanks for this.. I think I used comm only.. basically this command solves my purpose..

Comment: @user1588737 you're welcome! It seems you are not familiar with Q&A procedure on SO. If any answer worked for you, consider accepting it by clicking on hollow green tick mark besides answer. I observe that you haven't accepted answer for any of your questions so far.

Comment: accepted the answer.. thx a lot for pointing this.. was not aware of it